# python framework supporting CLI, cross platform GUI, web application

Tags: python, django, kivy

I am wondering if there is any python framework or compatible frameworks which support development bioinformatics CLI, cross platform GUI (Linux, Android, iOS, Windows) and Web Application with minimal code changes. Kivy + Django seems to be a good bet but not so straitforward. Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The question is about which framework has cli, gui and web features which is hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy+Django will not give you a CLI.

No framework will give you all 3 out-of-the-box you'll have to design your app as a library and use it in each:

common_lib:

- docopt -> CLI wrapper
- bottle/django -> Web Wrapper
- kivy -> desktop mobile Wrapper

In this approach you won't get much from django, you are better of with bottle/flask